# How can i move my camera?

Tags: camera

I know how I can rotate but how can I move up and down or sideways? Google didnt found anything useful

I read I can do it with Ctrl + c or . but the first one just fixed the camera at a point where it made everything even worse and . just did nothing

Comment: The camera is on object in blender, and its object transforms behave much like as (eg) meshes, or lights. After selecting the camera, try the usual G, S, R keys, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move objects you need to select them then press <kbd>G</kbd> to Grap and transform them. After pressing <kbd>G</kbd> you can press <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd> to move along a certain axis.

To move the view in the 3DView, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Middle mouse button and move your mouse

Comment: I dont want to move a object, I just want to move the camera where I can see everything

Comment: @blueYOSHI a camera is an object, just select it and then use G to move it.

Comment: I meant the whole view, everything I can see, I dont know how to describe it better

Answer (score 0):

In Object mode, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> plus <kbd>ALT</kbd> plus <kbd>0</kbd> to get your camera view. Then select the rectangle border, press <kbd>G</kbd> and move the view with the mouse to set your camera in the correct position you wish.